# Tumbletrain-style train image displaying?

Tags: php, css

http://tumbletrain.com/
What I want to know how to do is KIND of based on this. What this site does is take a tumblr username, and display their profile picture in the "train". I'd like to take user-uploaded images and display them in order of upload, deleting the images after a certain amount of new images has been uploaded much like tumbletrain does it. Any insight as to how I'd do this? Thanks.(:

Comment: That's kind of the thing, I'm not even sure where I'd start on something like that.

Comment: No idea at all? You've never written a page that takes user uploads? You've never had to sort something? You must have a little idea.

Comment: Not really. I'm insanely new to all this. If I knew what method I would use to do it, I could figure the rest out. I just don't know the method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the tumblr name to find their profile image (hopefully it's obvious), then add that to a MYSQL database. I'd then use PHP to run a query that selected the most recent 25 or whatever, then write out some HTML that included the images.

All in all, a few lines of PHP with a bit of HTML/CSS.

I'd recommend reading through a few of the www.tizag.com tutorials about PHP and MYSQL to get a handle on how to do this.

Comment: I'm not going for the tumblr name. Just personally uploaded images.

Comment: Well, same idea, just put the image into a database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Then you'll have to break it down into smaller and smaller pieces until you have a piece to start with. If you're totally new to PHP then start with a good (*recent*) PHP book or tutorial. Once you have a handle on the language and things like taking user input and so on you'll have a better idea of what piece of your project to tackle first. The main thing is to do the smallest unit of work possible--in fact, that is basically the essence of almost all programming: breaking your problem down into pieces, then breaking those pieces into smaller pieces still, until you find a piece that you know how to solve. Unfortunately there are no shortcuts, but with patience and diligence you can break down any problem and solve it.